# How can I fix the deadlock?

Tags: multithreading, go, goroutine

The programm must print sqrt of num if I write to first channel, 3*num if to secon, complete if to  stop. I can't understand where is channel blocked.

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
)

func main() {
ch1, ch2 := make(chan int), make(chan int)
stop := make(chan struct{})

r := calculator(ch1, ch2, stop)

//ch1 <- 3
ch2 <- 2
//<-stop
fmt.Println(<-r)

}

func calculator(firstChan <-chan int, secondChan <-chan int, stopChan <-chan struct{}) <-chan int {
returnChan := make(chan int)
go func() {
    defer close(returnChan)
    select {
    case <-firstChan:
        returnChan <- (<-firstChan) * (<-firstChan)
    case <-secondChan:
        returnChan <- (<-secondChan) * 3
    case <-stopChan:
        close(returnChan)
    }
}()
return returnChan
}
```

Comment: You're reading far too many times from your channels. Read __once__ and store the value in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading from the case statement:

```
case <-firstChan
```

and within case block:

```
...(<-firstChan) * (<-firstChan)
```

all together you read three times when only one was sent into the channel.

Get the value to a var in the case statement and use it in the block like below:

```
func calculator(firstChan <-chan int, secondChan <-chan int, stopChan <-chan struct{}) <-chan int {
    returnChan := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        defer close(returnChan)
        select {
        case firstChanVal := <-firstChan:
            returnChan <- firstChanVal * firstChanVal
        case firstChanVal := <-secondChan:
            returnChan <- firstChanVal * 3
        case <-stopChan:
            close(returnChan)
        }
    }()
    return returnChan
}
```

[Go play ground demo](https://go.dev/play/p/l3wayOyZxuy)

Answer (score 0):

When you call <-firstChan, the program will be paused and wait for a value to send to firstChan, you call 3 times <-firstChan while you only send 1 time, the program will pause forever

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).